# Clear coat over epoxy?

Tags: finishing, epoxy

I just did a pretty big piece of cherry with epoxy resin and there are a few spots that didn’t get covered adequately. Got a light coat but you can see the texture of the wood and not a glassy epoxy coating. The epoxy is almost dry.

I would rather not do an entire second coating. This also does not have to be perfect, I would just like to get it a little more glassy so it’s not so obvious.

Is there a spray I can use on this section to gloss it up? Or even coat the entire piece in a light spray?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful results.

Absolutely, epoxy takes other finish very well, as it is completely inert once its hardened. That looks great by the way.

I have used spar varnish on top of epoxy for a boat before. I've also sprayed high gloss clear coat - if you have a hvlp spray gun, I recommend that over a can for better results.

A very fine sanding with 400 grit first, and then a thorough cleaning is in order before spraying

Answer (score 1):

Because epoxy is a high build film finish, you want the surface to be flat and level before you put something else on it.

So that means either sanding the surface flat or pouring another layer of epoxy to cover the missed spots and the rest of the surface.

Epoxy will achieve a high sheen if you sand to high grits, likely wet sanding as you get into the really high grits.